Long term debt calculation in balance sheet - Yahoo vs Marketwatch
I am trying to calculate the long term debt from the balance sheet, comparing yahoo finance with marketwatch.
Let's take MSFT as example. In yahoo finance, the quarterly "Long Term Debt And Capital Lease Obligation" is the sum of "Long Term Debt" and "Long Term Capital Lease Obligation":

https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT/balance-sheet/
In marketwatch financials, the two entries are roughly the same (here they are called "Long-Term Debt excl. Capitalized Leases" and "Capitalized Lease Obligations", but their sum displayed as "Long-Term Debt" is higher in the case of MSFT:

https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/msft/financials/balance-sheet/quarter
Do you have any idea what is missing to reconstruct the long term debt as shown in marketwatch from yahoo finance? And which component of debt in marketwatch is being summed up to give the final long term debt?
Thanks

The item not being shown clearly and separately by MarketWatch (MW) under the long-term debt is the long term operating lease liabilities (screenshot from Microsoft’s investor relations website).

However, you can’t get that from Yahoo Finance (YF) because it is shown within other non-current liabilities together with other items without a breakdown in YF. To get it separately and reconcile the long term debt at MW with its components, you need to refer to yet another source such as the balance sheet announced by  Microsoft itself shown above.
